# Cannot locate link css or xpath

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubymine

I started to learn ruby (rspec , rubymine).
I want to do simple click action but I have a problem.
Id and name does not exist so, I should use xpath or css.

I tried  #click on contact link:

```
driver.find_element(:css, 'html>body>footer>div>div>section:nth-child(3)>a:nth-child(1)').click + ' :: absolute path'
```

xpath showed me:

```
 /x:html/x:body/x:footer/x:div/x:div/x:section[3]/x:a[1]
```

link is:

```
<a href="/k/k.aspx?action=custserv&amp;topic=contact" title="Contakt ">Contact</a>
```

and this is FIRST link in:

```
section class="link-block link-collection col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"
```

and section class is placed in `div: class="row"`

and this is here: `<footer class="footer" role="info">`

and this is inside: `<body data-touch="false" class="abc">`

[image]

Can anybody help me?

Comment: and where is the question?

Comment: You could go by the link text content here, that's more save for future changes.

Comment: link text content here, so where and how?:) something was not copied i think: <a href="/k/k.aspx?action=custserv&amp;topic=contact" title="Contact">Contact</a>

Comment: works with:driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*[@title="Contact"]').click  but when title will change it will not work..

Comment: Is this is a spec? Then yes - when the text changes... the spec should fail and then you change the spec to the new text. For a capybara spec you are expected to test what the user actually sees - ie click on the content that is actually displayed to the user... not the CSS classes.

Comment: Yes this is rspec :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used now Css but...it clicks on another links and css is the same! strange..hm
css: .footer .container .row .link-block h4 + a

so, how can I do this with xpath?;/
I used
@driver.find_element(:xpath, '//html/body/footer/div/div/section[3]/a[1]').click and it works:) but..what if sth will be changed on page?